# Who is this character in Wagnaria / Working?

Tags: wagnaria

The character in the image below appears a few times throughout the series.
She looks a bit like Yamada but Yamada is never seen wearing glasses while talking to the rest of the staff.

The image was taken at the 12:10 mark of EP11 but she appears in other episodes as well, although rarely.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that is [Maya Matsumoto](http://wagnaria.wikia.com/wiki/Maya_Matsumoto), the self proclaimed "perfectly normal" member of the staff.

[image: Maya Matsumoto]

On the 13th episode of the first 2 Seasons she has a speaking role in which in the first season she actually introduces herself. she also has a speaking role in the 3rd episode of Season 3

Also in the Artbook that comes with the Season 2 Premium Edition from NISA you can find her making comments on a number of pages